# NodeJS script running but logging nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, console.log

so I am writing a function to get biggest divisor,
and I am running it in VScode using command
$ -node script.js
it is logging nothing, what am I missing?
here is the content of script.js :

```
let LFfinder = num => {
    let result = num;
    for (let i = num - 1; i > 1 && result === num; i--) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            result = i;
            return result;
        }
        if (!i) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
};
LFfinder(15);
```

Comment: How do you know the code is running? I suggest adding a `console.log()` as the first line in your code to see if it prints.

Comment: I actually run it in chrome and it works for small numbers, I ran it with input number 600851475143 and it seemed to get stuck, so I tried switching to NodeJS

Comment: That is extra information that would be helpful in your original question. Read [this artile](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. I suggest adding more `console.log()` statements so that you can see when any of your `if` statements execute. The input 15 will work just as well to show the problem as 600851475143 because neither is prime.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing console.log() at the place where control is not reaching as per your logic. Try writing before you return the value

```
let LFfinder = num => {
    let result = num;
    for (let i = num - 1; i > 1 && result === num; i--) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            result = i;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
        if (!i) {
         console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

};
LFfinder(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `return` in the loop. Because of return the console.log statement is never reached. And the else part is not required. This will work:

```
let LFfinder = num => {
  let result = num;
  for (let i = num - 1; i > 1 && result === num; i--) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
          result = i;
          break;
      }
  }
  console.log(result);
};

LFfinder(15);
LFfinder(19);
LFfinder(200);
```

Note that you don't need to loop through till end. The first instance you find is the greatest, so save further iteration with `break`.

Also, it's better that the function returns a value instead of logging the answer.

```
let LFfinder = num => {
  let result = num;
  for (let i = num - 1; i > 1 && result === num; i--) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
          result = i;
          break;
      }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(LFfinder(15));
console.log(LFfinder(19));
console.log(LFfinder(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

its working fine, please check the link, i've tried
https://repl.it/@HarshSrivastav1/playgroundams